# How to output fpdf in php

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, fpdf

How can I create a pdf file for this using fpdf? So when I clicked a `btnSubmit`, there should be like a pdf file that consist all my data that I filled out and it will also store to my db.

Please help me to solve this, I'm a beginner. Thanks! My db connection is connections.php

```
$lname = $fname = $midname = $address = $nfather = $nmother = $guardian = $contactnum = $relationship = $bday = $gender = $status = "";

//ERROR NOTIFICATION FOR FILLING THE FORMS
$lnameErr = $fnameErr = $midnameErr = $addressErr = $nfatherErr = $nmotherErr = $guardianErr = $contactnumErr = $relationshipErr = $bdayErr = $genderErr = $statusErr = "";

//$_POST means, pagpapasa ng data - GLOBAL VARIABLE
if (isset($_POST["btnSubmit"])) {

  if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
    $lnameErr = "!";
  } else {
    $lname = $_POST["lname"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
    $fnameErr = "!";
  } else {
    $fname = $_POST["fname"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["midname"])) {
    $midnameErr = "!";
  } else {
    $midname = $_POST["midname"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
    $addressErr = "!";
  } else {
    $address = $_POST["address"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["nfather"])) {
    $nfatherErr = "!";
  } else {
    $nfather = $_POST["nfather"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["nmother"])) {
    $nmotherErr = "!";
  } else {
    $nmother = $_POST["nmother"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["guardian"])) {
    $guardianErr = "!";
  } else {
    $guardian = $_POST["guardian"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["contactnum"])) {
    $contactnumErr = "!";
  } else {
    $contactnum = $_POST["contactnum"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["relationship"])) {
    $relationshipErr = "!";
  } else {
    $relationship = $_POST["relationship"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["bday"])) {
    $bdayErr = "!";
  } else {
    $bday = $_POST["bday"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "!";
  } else {
    $gender = $_POST["gender"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["status"])) {
    $statusErr = "!";
  } else {
    $status = $_POST["status"];
  }

  // check if it only contains letters and whitespace
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $lname)) {
    $lnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
  }
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $fname)) {
    $fnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
  }
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $midname)) {
    $midnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
  }
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $nmother)) {
    $nmotherErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
  }
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $nfather)) {
    $nfatherErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
  }
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $relationship)) {
    $relationshipErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
  } else {


    if (!empty($lname) && !empty($fname) && !empty($midname) && !empty($address) && !empty($nfather) && !empty($nmother) && !empty($guardian) && !empty($contactnum) && !empty($relationship) && !empty($bday) && !empty($gender) && !empty($status)) {

      //if it's already registered
      $get_record_name = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM admission_form WHERE lname='$lname' AND fname='$fname'") or die(mysqli_error($db));

      if (mysqli_num_rows($get_record_name) > 0) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Sorry, it looks like this student is already registered") </script>';
      } else {


        //date format
        $date = date('l | F d, Y h:i:s A');

        // query for admission_form         
        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO admission_form(lname, fname, midname, address, nfather, nmother, guardian, contactnum, relationship, bday, gender, dateJoined, status)
          VALUES('$lname', '$fname', '$midname', '$address', '$nfather', '$nmother', '$guardian', '$contactnum', '$relationship', '$bday', '$gender', '$date', '$status')
          ") or die(mysqli_error()); 
          echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Admission succesful") </script>';
          //echo '<script>document.location='main.php';</script>'; //action page
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: read this 
http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/index.php

Comment: say hello to SQL Injection